# "Empty path name is not legal" error occuring when running application in x64

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to convert a running program created in VB to x64 (currently x86) but when I change to x64 and debug, I get the following error:

[image: Error message screenshot]

Comment: PrintFileName1 is an empty string.

Comment: Can you check the value of `PrintFileName01`? This seems unrelated to x86 vs x64.

Comment: Please refer to [ask]. Relevant code should be copied into the question.

Comment: Thanks for your responses but I'm not sure what to do? sorry I'm new to vb and running this task the first time Thanks

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and inspect `PrintFileName01`.  Find out why it is `Nothing` or empty.